# Switching views on an InfoPath form using rules

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have an InfoPath form with a drop down option. What I want to do is that as soon as a user selects an option the form changes to that view. I've set a Form Load rule to switch to view X when X is selected in the drop down, but it's not working. Is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Switching can be only done via button click. Below are some work around you can try

1. If the drop downs have only few options you can try converting those to button and format it to looks better
2. Remove views and use sections.